# How to select multiple items with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this `select` with the `multiple` option enabled:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="weekday" class="form-label">Weekday</label>
    <select name="weekday" id="weekday" class="form-select" size="7" multiple aria-label="Weekday">
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Before enabling the `multiple` option, I was able to programmatically select an item in this way:

```
document.querySelector("#weekday").value = "5"
```

I cannot understand the right syntax to select multiple items via Javascript.
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) I find nothing useful.

Say I want to select `0`, `2` and `4`. How should I change the above call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get each wanted option and set the `selected` property to true for each one.

```js
const values = ['0', '2', '4'];
values.forEach(v => document.querySelector(`option[value='${v}']`).selected = true);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="weekday" class="form-label">Weekday</label>
    <select name="weekday" id="weekday" class="form-select" size="7" multiple aria-label="Weekday">
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mark No, this is standard JavaScript. You can see that this snippet does not load any external scripts.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't understand the `$` at first sight. It works!

Comment: @Mark Happy to help. The `${}` is used for string interpolation in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

You can select option using `querySelector` then you can easily add `selected` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector("#weekday [value='5']").setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="weekday" class="form-label">Weekday</label>
    <select name="weekday" id="weekday" class="form-select" size="7" multiple aria-label="Weekday">
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so basically you're saying I can identify a single item in the selector. Then I can repeat the `setAttribute` call for every item I need. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, Sir You understood correctly.